# The type or namespace name 'vector' could not be found

Tags: unity3d

Во время написания скрипта возникают две ошибки, которые я СОВСЕМ не могу понять, а то есть исправить.

Первая ошибка - *The type or namespace name 'vector' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Вторая ошибка - *All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!*

сам код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerControler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float JumpForce;
    private float moveInput;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private void start()
    {
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizont");
        rb.velocity = new vector(moveInput * speed,rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Укажите язык в метках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вместо vector напишите Vector2